# How stringbuilder append work

Tags: stringbuffer

How many objects will be created by below code and please explain how?

```
StringBuilder s=new StringBuilder();
s.append("hi"+"java"+"test");
```

Comment: Firstly of all, what you wrote is wrong, it should be `StringBuilder s=new StringBuilder();
s.append("hi");s.append("java");s.append("test");`

Comment: This [msdn doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) will tell you all you need to know, then you can look through this [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs,adf60ee46ebd299f) and that will give you the how many. But strings are more to do with address and pointers rather than objects.

Answer (score 0):

So from the [msdn docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) at the bottom of the page:

> The following example illustrates how a StringBuilder object allocates
> new memory and increases its capacity dynamically as the string
> assigned to the object expands. The code creates a StringBuilder
> object by calling its default (parameterless) constructor. **The default
> capacity of this object is 16 characters**, and its maximum capacity is
> more than 2 billion characters. Appending the string "This is a
> sentence." results in a new memory allocation because the string
> length (19 characters) exceeds the default capacity of the
> StringBuilder object. The **capacity of the object doubles to 32
> characters, the new string is added**, and the length of the object now
> equals 19 characters. The code then appends the string "This is an
> additional sentence." to the value of the StringBuilder object 11
> times. Whenever the **append operation causes the length of the
> StringBuilder object to exceed its capacity, its existing capacity is
> doubled and the Append operation succeeds.**

I highlighted in bold the important parts.

So basically, the steps are:

1. StringBuilder creates a length to hold some strings
2. when the length is surpassed it will double it until it can hold the strings
3. Looking at line 373 in the [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs,adf60ee46ebd299f) to output the string it will read through the memory addresses putting it together... from a very high level.

So thing to remember that it doesnt create objects, it's just dynamic reallocation of memory space to handle the new length of strings determined when `append` is called.

### To Answer your question further

Scenario A), we set a length:

```
var s = new StringBuilder(10);
s.Append("hijavatest");
```

This should create a string builder of capacity 10, and store that string in it.

Scenario B), we don't specify a length:

```
var s = new StringBuilder();
s.Append("hi");
s.Append("java");
s.Append("test");
```

This will create the default capacity of a string builder: 16. and shouldn't change size to append all the new strings.

Scenario C), we set a small length:

```
var s = new StringBuilder(3);
s.Append("hi");
s.Append("java"); // doubles capacity to 6
s.Append("test"); // doubles capacity to 12
```

This will double the capacity till it can store all the string, in this case 12.

Run the below code in dotnetfiddle:

```
using System;
using System.Text;  

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
      ScenarioA();
        ScenarioB();
        ScenarioC();
   }

   private static void ShowSBInfo(StringBuilder sb)
   {
      foreach (var prop in sb.GetType().GetProperties()) {
         if (prop.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)
            Console.Write("{0}: {1:N0}    ", prop.Name, prop.GetValue(sb));
      }
      Console.WriteLine();
   }
    
    private static void ScenarioA()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Scenario A");
        var sb = new StringBuilder(10);
        ShowSBInfo(sb);
        sb.Append("hijavatest");    
        ShowSBInfo(sb);
    }
    
    private static void ScenarioB()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Scenario B");
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        ShowSBInfo(sb);
        sb.Append("hi");
        ShowSBInfo(sb);
        sb.Append("java");
        ShowSBInfo(sb);
        sb.Append("test");  
        ShowSBInfo(sb);
    }
    
    private static void ScenarioC()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Scenario C");
        var sb = new StringBuilder(3);
        ShowSBInfo(sb);
        sb.Append("hi");
        ShowSBInfo(sb);
        sb.Append("java"); // doubles capacity to 6
        ShowSBInfo(sb);
        sb.Append("test"); // doubles capacity to 12    
        ShowSBInfo(sb);
    }
}
```